# We have a launchpad team?

Tags: discussion, launchpad

I was looking through the google tubes and [found this](https://launchpad.net/~askubuntu) - it appears that there is a AskUbuntu launchpad.net team.

I just wanted to bring this up - is there anything we want to do with this? Note that there is also the [`askubuntu-tools`](https://launchpad.net/~askubuntu-tools) group as well, with a PPA for StackApplet and the Unity lens.

Comment: I think it would be great if we could produce tools or maintain a PPA for Ask Ubuntu/SE tools in an askubuntu team PPA.

Comment: I hadn't seen this before either. I think the real questions are what is the team for and who should join?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's in the team's description. These are people responsible for managing it, sort of administrators.

Comment: @rafalcieslak Incorrect. It's for those who support it - meaning that it's those who use it. It's for the community, not just for the moderators. With that being said, the question I asked in my post is there anything that we want to do with it?

Comment: a start would be pinging those people with this URL...